# How to connect a GigE camera directly to a computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing

We have a GigE camera attached to our network, capturiung images from a Python program and processing them for a computer vision task. The camera receives its IP address from our DHCP server, as usual, but it would also allow to set the IP address statically.

Now for testing I want to attach the camera directly to a Ubuntu 18.04 based computer, like a 1:1 connection from the computer to the camera, without a network switch etc. in between. So I guess I need to setup a DHCP server on that machine, or set the IP address of the camera statically.

But what else do I need to talk to the GigE camera from that computer? Do I have to manually set the routes etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give both devices a static IP address in the same subnet.  The gateway won't even matter.  Setting up a DHCP server would be massively over doing it.